# Entity vs ValueObject

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, domain-driven-design

I'm creating a RESTful webservice, which retrieves repository details from github and returns them. My code looks like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{owner}/{repositoryName}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public RepositoryDetails getRepositoryDetails(@PathVariable String owner, @PathVariable String repositoryName) throws Exception {
    log.info("Github repository details request: owner: " + owner + ", repository name: " + repositoryName);
    checkParameters(owner, repositoryName);
    RepositoryDetailsInternal repositoryDetailsInternal = repoService.getRepositoryDetails(owner, repositoryName);
    RepositoryDetails repositoryDetailsOutput = new RepositoryDetails(repositoryDetailsInternal, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
    return repositoryDetailsOutput;
}
```

As you can see, there are two important objects: `repositoryDetailsInternal` and `repositoryDetailsOutput`. `repositoryDetailsInternal` is the parsed response data from Github and `repositoryDetailsOutput` is the output object returned by my webservice.

**My question is: what is each of these objects - an entity or a value object?**

I'm leaning towards calling `repositoryDetailsInternal` an entity and `repositoryDetailsOutput` a value object, but I'd like some second opinion on that.
On one hand, `repositoryDetailsInternal` is something that can be changed over time (stargazers count can increase or decrease), but on the other hand in my application this object is immutable. 
**EDIT: I should also mention that `repositoryDetailsInternal` is cached using owner and repository name**, so it may be perceived as identity:

```
@Cacheable(REPO_DETAILS_CACHE)
    public RepositoryDetailsInternal getRepositoryDetails(String owner, String repositoryName) throws TimeoutException  {...}
```

`repositoryDetailsOutput` is also immutable and seems like a value object, because it represents a kind of a snapshot of repository state.

Comment: Maybe that's what you're after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161753/class-object-entity-whats-the-difference. IMHO (im)mutability is orthogonal to "being an entity", as they can be mutable or immutable (like you can have entity with e.g. past events which won't change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell both objects are `Value Objects` even if the value returned by the web service can vary because  they don't have an **`Identity`**.

I can imagine a more complex scenario in which they could become `entities` but I don't know if this is your case (i.e. you could store an evolution in time of the stars a project has).

Comment: Please see the edit. Does it change your view on the issue?

Comment: Hmm, no. A github repository seems like a `Entity` but in the Github Remote Bounded Context, in yours is a `Value Object`.

Comment: Anyway, a piece of advice, if you are unsure make it a `Value Object`